# Cancel option on JavaScript confirmation box returns true condition only

Tags: javascript, php

I am printing some data using php on my webpage and giving "Edit" and "Delete" option next to it.

Now I have added a javascript confirmation page next to it using onclick.
Now when the user presses "OK" button, it executes the query as expected. But even when the user presses Cancel button, it still executes the query and deletes data.

```
if($total!=0)
        {

                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){

                    echo"<table><tr>

                    <td>".$result['address']."</td>
                    <td>".$result['telephone']."</td>
                    <td>".$result['phone']."</td>
                    <td>".$result['email']."</td>
                    <td><a href='contact_edit.php?id=$result[id]&address=$result[address]&telephone=$result[telephone]&phone=$result[phone]&email=$result[email]'>EDIT</td>
                    <td><a href='contact_delete.php?id=$result[id]' onclick='checkdelete()'>DELETE</a></td>
                    </tr></table>";
            }
        }
```

The javascript code:

```
<script>

function checkdelete() 
{
    confirm('ARE YOU SURE YOU WANNA DELETE?');
}

</script>
```

Should I wrap it in an if-else statement?

Comment: Calling `checkdelete()` does nothing in your code

Comment: The query is executed on a different page named "contact_delete.php" which in theory should run on clicking "Yes" in the confirmation box. It does so in my code but on clicking cancel, it still executes the query on "contact_delete.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php:

```
echo "...
  ...
  <td>
   <a href='#' onclick='checkdelete(\"contact_delete.php?id=".$result[id]."\")'>
     DELETE
   </a>
  </td>
  ... ";
```

in js:

```
<script>

function checkdelete(url) 
{
    if( confirm('ARE YOU SURE YOU WANNA DELETE?') ){
         window.location.replace(url);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can you explain the reason for the same?

Comment: In your code, in a tag, you have two link and for this reason also if the user click cancel the link contact_delete.PHP is always execute. While with the @Khaled Alan code you execute the file PHP only when the user click OK...